# Gradle 5.4.1 solved my proxy issues. Could someone explain why?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, proxy

I'm working from behind a corporate proxy with android studio.
I was unable to get my dependencies with gradle since day 1 despite trying everything I could and checking every article that google threw at me with "gradle proxy" and "gradle proxy error".
Jcenter, maven and google repositories were all blocked.
I was able to resolve my problems by using a corporate Jfrog artifactory and by adding dependencies locally, but this approach was very error prone and uncomfortable.

A couple of weeks ago in one of our projects a colleague changed gradle-wrapper.properties distributionUrl attribute to gradle-5.4.1-all.zip and all of a sudden everything started to work perfectly. No more artifactory or local dependencies needed.

I checked the release notes of [gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/release-notes.html) but couldn't really find an answer on why this happened.

So at the moment I'm happy, but also curious. 
Does anyone have an idea about what changed in gradle that solved my problems?

Answer (score 1):

What was the previous version of Gradle before 5.4? I know Gradle switched from http to https for all network communication for security reasons, I can't remember which release that was.

Perhaps you had configured the https proxy settings in gradle.properties but had not configured the http proxy settings? In this instance the switch to https would have fixed the issue.

Comment: The previous version we used was 5.1.1.

Comment: You might be right, I did add http to gradle.properties as well, but I gave the same proxy url without mentioning the protocol.